# Purchase of pack of product not updating quantity in Inventory of the product

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am working on customizing then openERP 7.0.  I want to know how to handle the following use case in openERP

Example:

Consider 'Product A' from a supplier.  The supplier may sell the product as

```
-Box of 100 

-Box of 200 

-Box of 1000
```

What I did is, I have created the BoM for the 'Product A' with quantity 100 
say 'BoM of Product A(100)'.

Now, If i have created the PO for 'BoM of Product A(100)' of quantity 1 from supplier.  Validated that and received that.

In inventory, the 'quantity on hand' of product is as follows

```
 Product A - 0 
 BoM of Product A(100) - 1
```

I am expecting the result of 'quantity on hand' as follows

```
Product A - 100
BoM of Product A(100) - 1
```

How to handle this Pack of 'product' concept in openERP. Please help me on these.

Answer (score 2):

you have to enable " Manage different units of measure for products " from 
**setting--> warehouse**

and then you can define new **UOM** for the product with desired quantity. from
**Warehouse--> Configuration--> Unit of Measure**

Comment: Thanks for your answer Baiju.  Let me try your suggestion.